# SqlException was Unhandled

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to make a log in form in c# with database i don't know what to do and it is the code the error said the SQLException was Unhandled on the part of sda.Fill(dt) here is the code

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\LOUI;Initial Catalog=login_db;User ID=sa;Password=1029384756");
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count (*) From login_tbl where username = '" + User_txt.Text + "'and password = '" +Pass_txt.Text+ "'",con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {

            this.Hide();
            adminpanel ap = new adminpanel();
            ap.Show();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Check Username or Password");
        }
```

Comment: Wrap the code in a try/catch block and handle the exception.  The exception is telling you what the problem is.  Also, be aware that your code is *wide open* to **SQL injection**.  From a security perspective, this means users can execute arbitrary code on your database.  From a debugging perspective, this means we don't even know what SQL code you're executing here.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `sda.Fill(dt);` with

```
try
{
    sda.Fill(dt);
}
catch (SQLException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

and edit your question to include the new output.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\LOUI;InitialCatalog=login_db;User ID=sa;Password=1029384756");//problem is here

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count (*) From login where name = '" + User_txt.Text + "'and pass = '" + Pass_txt.Text + "'", con); 

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt); 

    if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
    {
        this.Hide();
        adminpanel ap = new adminpanel();
        ap.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Check Username or Password");
    }
}
catch (Exception z)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Connection error");
}
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting and add an explanation about the changes. Besides, this is not really an answer.

Comment: @PeterBons I just fixed the formatting. Just waiting for approval :)

Comment: This is exactly the same reply, as mine.

Comment: @Benni: Well, not *exactly* the same.  Yours at least logs the error, whereas this one completely ignores the error for no reason.  By contrast, your answer is useful.  This one is not.